# Pip for Python 3.1

Tags: pip, python-3.1

I have been trying to install pip on my Python 3.1, in order to be able to convert .py files to .exe files. I have been searching around the internet, finding stuff like sudo, some bootstrap links and things like that but nothing worked yet. If anyone got any clue how can I install it, please help.

Comment: What O.S. do you use?

Comment: I don't believe Python 3.1 is usable. I think Python 3.4 is the minimum version to use and even it is too old and too problematic. Can you upgrade?